# Python based SVM library

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

Is there a Python based library providing an SVM implementation with a GPL or any other opensource license? I have come across a few that provide an SVM wrapper for the SVM logic encoded in C, but none that are coded entirely in Python.

Regards,

Mandar

Answer (score 2):

[`libsvm`](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) has Python bindings.

**Edit**

Googling found [`PyML`](http://pyml.sourceforge.net/), but I haven't used it.

Comment: yeah i tried libsvm, it has python bindings but core SVM logic is still in C. that's not what i am looking for. rather i need the logic in python

Comment: That looks like it will do the trick :) thanks :) wonder how I didn't come across it

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this link, it has a big collection of machine learning software, it lists 50+ libraries that have been written in Python:

http://mloss.org/software/language/python/